# read and write exif metadata in Python from a TIF image

Tags: python, metadata, tiff, exif

i am looking a library or a specific function in Python to read and write the `exif metadata` from a TIFF image by a digital camera

My image in 16-bit TIFF format has the follow proprieties, identify with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php):

```
Properties:
date:create: 2015-09-02T16:01:49-06:00
date:modify: 2015-09-02T18:00:37-06:00
exif:ExposureTime: 0.00125
exif:FNumber: 2.8
exif:FocalLength: 16
exif:ISOSpeedRatings: 400
signature: e72808cba367184ab5c8f9c06d52701c7850e114155676857d2912b4743f243a
tiff:alpha: unspecified
tiff:artist:
tiff:endian: lsb
tiff:make: Sony
tiff:model: NEX-7
tiff:photometric: RGB
tiff:rows-per-strip: 1
tiff:software: dcraw v9.25
tiff:timestamp: 2014:07:28 08:34:56
```

if i read and write in Python with the comumn libreries (es: [tifffile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tifffile)) i lose my metadata

```
import tifffile as tiff
from skimage import io
myimage = 'C:\\foo.tiff'
image = tiff.imread(myimage)
io.imsave("C:\\foo_new.tiff", image)
```

form ImageMagick

```
Properties:
date:create: 2015-09-17T15:58:07-06:00
date:modify: 2015-09-17T16:00:34-06:00
signature: e72808cba367184ab5c8f9c06d52701c7850e114155676857d2912b4743f243a
tiff:alpha: unspecified
tiff:endian: lsb
tiff:photometric: RGB
tiff:rows-per-strip: 1
tiff:software: tifffile.py
tiff:timestamp: 2015:09:17 16:00:27
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/):

```
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename='test.tif') as image:
    for k, v in image.metadata.items():
        print("{}: {}".format(k, v))

    image.save(filename='copy.tif')
```

Comment: Thanks. But for example if i wish to modify my data (es: from 16-bit to 8-bit) can i do with this library?

Comment: `Wand` is a wrapper around `ImageMagick`, so if you can create a command line comand that works with your files then it should be possible to write Python code with the same capabilities. For example, try to manipulate [Image.depth](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.1/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.depth) value.

Comment: `Wand` does not support writing the metadata so it's not a solution for this question.

Comment: You could take a look at [PyExifTool](https://smarnach.github.io/pyexiftool/) which is a python wrapper for exiftool.